# SpringWebserviceProducer nullpointer camel unit test spring route

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I've used one of camel example as use case:

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/examples/camel-example-spring-ws/

Let say we would like to create a unit test for this project:

```
package org.apache.camel.example.server;

import org.apache.camel.test.spring.CamelSpringTestSupport;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;

public class IncrementRouteTest extends CamelSpringTestSupport {

    @Override
    protected AbstractApplicationContext createApplicationContext() {
        return new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{
            "/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-ws-servlet.xml"});
    }

    @Test
    public void testSendMatchingMessage() throws Exception {
        template.sendBodyAndHeader("spring-ws:rootqname:{http://camel.apache.org/example/increment}incrementRequest?endpointMapping=#endpointMapping",
            "<msg>asd</msg>",
            "head1",
            "headVal1");
    }

}
```

To simplify I skipped extra endpoint creation mocking it and validating if result is satisfied..

running above code will result in:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running org.apache.camel.example.server.IncrementRouteTest
2014-07-09 12:36:50,682 [main           ] INFO  IncrementRouteTest             - ********************************************************************************
2014-07-09 12:36:50,683 [main           ] INFO  IncrementRouteTest             - Testing: testSendMatchingMessage(org.apache.camel.example.server.IncrementRouteTest)
2014-07-09 12:36:50,683 [main           ] INFO  IncrementRouteTest             - ********************************************************************************
2014-07-09 12:36:50,808 [main           ] INFO  ileSystemXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@911ed70: startup date [Wed Jul 09 12:36:50 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
2014-07-09 12:36:50,865 [main           ] INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader        - Loading XML bean definitions from file [/home/wojtek/repo/coi/camel/apache-camel-2.13.1/examples/camel-example-spring-ws/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-ws-servlet.xml]
2014-07-09 12:36:51,900 [main           ] INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory     - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@70d343dc: defining beans [template,consumerTemplate,camelContext:beanPostProcessor,camelContext,incrementRoute,myFileRoute,endpointMapping,loggingInterceptor,validatingInterceptor,increment]; root of factory hierarchy
2014-07-09 12:36:52,105 [main           ] INFO  PayloadValidatingInterceptor   - Validating using file [/home/wojtek/repo/coi/camel/apache-camel-2.13.1/examples/camel-example-spring-ws/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/increment.xsd]
2014-07-09 12:36:52,232 [main           ] INFO  SpringCamelContext             - Apache Camel 2.13.1 (CamelContext: camelContext) is starting
2014-07-09 12:36:52,232 [main           ] INFO  ManagedManagementStrategy      - JMX is enabled
2014-07-09 12:36:52,398 [main           ] INFO  DefaultTypeConverter           - Loaded 181 type converters
2014-07-09 12:36:52,468 [main           ] INFO  SpringCamelContext             - AllowUseOriginalMessage is enabled. If access to the original message is not needed, then its recommended to turn this option off as it may improve performance.
2014-07-09 12:36:52,468 [main           ] INFO  SpringCamelContext             - StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
2014-07-09 12:36:52,470 [main           ] INFO  JaxbDataFormat                 - Creating JAXBContext with contextPath: org.apache.camel.example.server.model and ApplicationContextClassLoader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@13883d5f
2014-07-09 12:36:52,515 [main           ] INFO  SpringCamelContext             - Route: route1 started and consuming from: Endpoint[spring-ws://rootqname:(http://camel.apache.org/example/increment)incrementRequest?endpointMapping=%23endpointMapping]
2014-07-09 12:36:52,515 [main           ] INFO  SpringCamelContext             - Total 1 routes, of which 1 is started.
2014-07-09 12:36:52,520 [main           ] INFO  SpringCamelContext             - Apache Camel 2.13.1 (CamelContext: camelContext) started in 0.283 seconds
2014-07-09 12:36:52,551 [main           ] INFO  IncrementRouteTest             - ********************************************************************************
2014-07-09 12:36:52,551 [main           ] INFO  IncrementRouteTest             - Testing done: testSendMatchingMessage(org.apache.camel.example.server.IncrementRouteTest)
2014-07-09 12:36:52,551 [main           ] INFO  IncrementRouteTest             - Took: 0.029 seconds (29 millis)
2014-07-09 12:36:52,551 [main           ] INFO  IncrementRouteTest             - ********************************************************************************
2014-07-09 12:36:52,552 [main           ] INFO  SpringCamelContext             - Apache Camel 2.13.1 (CamelContext: camelContext) is shutting down
2014-07-09 12:36:52,552 [main           ] INFO  DefaultShutdownStrategy        - Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 10 seconds)
2014-07-09 12:36:52,560 [ - ShutdownTask] INFO  DefaultShutdownStrategy        - Route: route1 shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[spring-ws://rootqname:(http://camel.apache.org/example/increment)incrementRequest?endpointMapping=%23endpointMapping]
2014-07-09 12:36:52,560 [main           ] INFO  DefaultShutdownStrategy        - Graceful shutdown of 1 routes completed in 0 seconds
2014-07-09 12:36:52,572 [main           ] INFO  SpringCamelContext             - Apache Camel 2.13.1 (CamelContext: camelContext) uptime 0.340 seconds
2014-07-09 12:36:52,572 [main           ] INFO  SpringCamelContext             - Apache Camel 2.13.1 (CamelContext: camelContext) is shutdown in 0.020 seconds
2014-07-09 12:36:52,573 [main           ] INFO  ileSystemXmlApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@911ed70: startup date [Wed Jul 09 12:36:50 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
2014-07-09 12:36:52,573 [main           ] INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory     - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@70d343dc: defining beans [template,consumerTemplate,camelContext:beanPostProcessor,camelContext,incrementRoute,myFileRoute,endpointMapping,loggingInterceptor,validatingInterceptor,increment]; root of factory hierarchy
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.06 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.apache.camel.example.server.IncrementRouteTest
testSendMatchingMessage(org.apache.camel.example.server.IncrementRouteTest)  Time elapsed: 1.901 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[Message: <msg>asd</msg>]
    at org.apache.camel.component.spring.ws.SpringWebserviceProducer.process(SpringWebserviceProducer.java:89)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProducer.process(UnitOfWorkProducer.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$2.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:378)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$2.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:346)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:242)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.sendExchange(ProducerCache.java:346)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.send(ProducerCache.java:184)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:124)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeader(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:163)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeader(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:159)
    at org.apache.camel.example.server.IncrementRouteTest.testSendMatchingMessage(IncrementRouteTest.java:18)
```

After some debugging I got some more info .. line 89
            body = getEndpoint().getConfiguration().getWebServiceTemplate().sendSourceAndReceive(sourcePayload, callback, SOURCE_EXTRACTOR);

getWebServiceTemplate() is causing nullpointer ...

It work perfectly when using :

```
package org.apache.camel.example.server;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class FileRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file://target/inbox")
            .to("file://target/outbox");

    }

}
```

and inside test:

```
package org.apache.camel.example.server;

import org.apache.camel.EndpointInject;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.test.spring.CamelSpringTestSupport;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;

public class IncrementRouteTest extends CamelSpringTestSupport {

    @Override
    protected AbstractApplicationContext createApplicationContext() {
        return new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{
            "/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-ws-servlet.xml"});
    }

    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:file:target/outbox/hello.txt")
    protected MockEndpoint resultEndpoint;

    @Test
    public void testSendMatchingMessage() throws Exception {

        template.sendBodyAndHeader("file://target/inbox",
            "Hello World", "asd", "hello.txt");
        resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();

    }

}
```

What could be the caused of NullPointer at SpringWebserviceProducer.java:89
How to test spring based route  ?